# How to check if two inputs (or more) will create a duplicate in an html table, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

After hours of research with no results, I'm here to ask for your help.

I have an input field and a select field in a form, and a table generated with php from my database where I display teams names and their region like this :

```
+-----------+---------+
| Team Name | Region  |
+-----------+---------+
| name1     | region1 |
| name2     | region2 |
| name3     | region1 |
+-----------+---------+
```

I made a JavaScript function that prevents the user to add a name and a region into the database if there is already a team with this name. However, I want to allow duplicates of names, as long as the region is different, so I can have "name1 - region1" and "name1 - region2" for exemple.

So, is there a way to do this using jQuery please ? Here is the function I have to check only the label :

```
function checkLabel(labelInput, labelSaved) {
  let result = true;
  $('.label').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).html().toLowerCase()) === labelInput 
    && labelInput !== labelSaved) {
      result = false;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

And here is the code inside my foreach function, generating my table rows :

```
<?php
foreach ($tabMaintenanceTeam->getTab() as $maintenanceTeam) {
  $edit = 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm" data-action="edit" data-id="' . $maintenanceTeam->getId() . '" data-label="' . $maintenanceTeam->getLabel() . '" data-region="' . $maintenanceTeam->getRegion()->getId() . '"';
?>
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle label" <?= $edit ?>>
      <?= $maintenanceTeam->getLabel() ?>
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle region" <?= $edit ?>>
      <?= $maintenanceTeam->getRegion()->getLabel() ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

By the way I already have a MySQL request that already do the verification and prevent those duplicates, however I want to do a first check in javascript to avoid unnecessary database requests.

Comment: What is `labelInput` and `labelSaved`?

Comment: You still need to check if the region entered by the user already exists in the database or not. There are two ways you can do that:-
1 - Create a get request every time the user submits the value to check if the region is present (But it will increase your request to the API).
2 - If the amount of data is going to be small what you can do is get all the distinct regions and save at the frontend level for the check (This will reduce your unnecessary requests)

Comment: you can do it by ajax you send request if there is same name with region then show it to user and remove name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I managed to do it this way :

```
function checkLabelRegion(labelInput, labelSaved, region, regionSaved) {
    let result = true;
    let selectedOptionText = $("#region option:selected").text().toLowerCase();

    $('table > tbody > tr').each(function () {
        if (($.trim($(this).find('.label').html().toLowerCase()) === labelInput && labelInput !== labelSaved) && ($.trim($(this).find('.region').html().toLowerCase()) === selectedOptionText && region !== regionSaved)) {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

And for the html :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead class="thead-custom">
    <tr>
      <th><div class="cell-inner text-xs">Maintenance team</div></th>
      <th><div class="cell-inner text-xs">Region</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($tabMaintenanceTeam->getTab() as $maintenanceTeam) {
      $edit = 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm" data-action="edit" data-id="' . $maintenanceTeam->getId() . '" data-label="' . $maintenanceTeam->getLabel() . '" data-region="' . $maintenanceTeam->getRegion()->getId() . '"';
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle label" <?= $edit ?>><?= $maintenanceTeam->getLabel() ?></td>
        <td class="align-middle region" <?= $edit ?>><?= $maintenanceTeam->getRegion()->getLabel() ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This way it checks exclusively with JavaScript, and doesn't send an SQL request.

To answer the question "What are xxxSaved", they are hidden input fields where we store input data on form subit to get them back if the submit fail, to avoid having the user type everything again.